# how to remove duplicates using map

Tags: c++

im working on a homework assignment t that should print all pairs of integers that sum to val. I have so far finished except It prints duplicate values (ie (3,1) and(1,3) for values that add to 4) . how can i remove these duplicate pairs of values?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void printPairs( vector<int> numbers, int val){
    int i;
    int temp;

    map<int,int>valMap;
    for(i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++){
      temp = val - numbers[i];
      if(temp >= 0 && valMap[temp] == 1){

        printf("Pair of integers that sum to val %d is (%d, %d) \n", val,                    numbers[i], temp);  

}
        valMap[numbers[i]] = 1;
}

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    vector <int> v(11);
    v[0]=1;
    v[1]=2;
    v[2]=3;
    v[3]=4;
    v[4]=5;
    v[5]=6;
    v[6]=7;
    v[7]=1;
    v[8]=2;
    v[9]=3;
    v[10]=4;


    printPairs(v,7);



    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code so that it's readable.  Thanks

Comment: You can add a condition to print only if the left value is lower than the right value, thus 1,3 would print but 3,1 won't

Comment: Don't use TAB characters for indentation, as you can see this doesn't work in markup. Convert these to 4 spaces instead.

Comment: yay that worked  @ ZivS , thank you!!! but it kinda feels like cheating lol

Answer (score 0):

This variant of printing function...

```
void printPairs( vector<int> numbers, int val){
    int i, j;
    map<int,int>valMap;
    // build a map
    for(i = 0; i < numbers.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        for(j = i; j < numbers.size(); j++)
        {
            if( (numbers[i] + numbers[j]) == val)
            {
                // use minimum value as a key, and max value as a value
                valMap[ (numbers[i] < numbers[j])?numbers[i]:numbers[j] ] = (numbers[i] >= numbers[j])?numbers[i]:numbers[j];
            }
        }
    }
    // print all map's values
    for(map<int,int>::iterator iter = valMap.begin(); iter !=valMap.end(); iter++)
    {
        printf("Pair of integers that sum to val %d is (%d, %d) \n", val, iter->first, iter->second);
    }
}
```

... gives the output ...

```
Pair of integers that sum to val 7 is (1, 6)
Pair of integers that sum to val 7 is (2, 5)
Pair of integers that sum to val 7 is (3, 4)
```

Comment: im supposed to have a runtime better than O(n^2).i ended up adding   numbers[i]<temp to my if statement ,if(temp >= 0 && valMap[temp] == 1 && numbers[i]<temp)   and it works. but it kinda feels like cheating lol

Comment: that was what my assignment was lol , this is what he gave us to use and he wanted it to be faster then n^2

Comment: @petrovich Please don't use snippets for non runnable code. You may add a link to an online compiler like ideone or coliru, to show a fully working sample.

Comment: i apologize , im still getting use to how things work around here